# strange potential plagiarism case(missed the acknowledgement page)

Tags: citations, advisor, plagiarism

Forgot to mention supervisor's name in the thesis(due to pressure) and submitted it and got an A for it. Can I be accused of plagiarism at a later date, if this professor wishes to push it forward? This professor was my thesis advisor or guide.There were some portions of the thesis which we both worked on it and some portion was mine. I missed the acknowledgment section

Comment: What kind of thesis, PhD, master, ...?

Comment: Master's thesis

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the Ph.D candidate is always considered the only author of the thesis and the only one to respond legally in case of plagiarism. Despite all the input introduced by your supervisor along your research, he will never be entitled to accuse you of plagiarism due to the lack of acknowledgements. This is just an impolite thing to do, nothing more.

Comment: I think it depends on the field as to whether advisors' names go on theses. Not in math, usually.

Comment: @paulgarrett really? Every thesis in every field I've ever seen lists the student as author and the advisor as advisor (sometimes in combination with an advisory board, the commitee, the reviewers or something similar)

Comment: @DSVA,  I understand your point. For a long time, that was my experience, too (I'm a mathematician). But in the last 10-20 years I've encountered many situations in engineering and computer science where, because the advisor supplied equipment and a room and a stipend, the students listed them as authors. There has been much discussion of such things on this and other similar sites.

Comment: @paulgarrett are you talking about publications during the PhD (in that case it's pretty common) or the actual thesis, which might contain the papers but even if that case I've never seen more than one author on the thesis itself. I also checked about 150 random theses on proquest right now and not a single one with more than a single author.

Comment: @DSVA, ah, yes, the distinction between "thesis" per se, and "papers in it or derived from it" are two different things. Maybe it's not so clear what exactly the issue is for the OP...